# Not printing values of array correctly (very beginner programming)

Tags: arrays, c, printing

```
int  main()
{
   int arr1[25], i,n;
   printf(" Input the number of elements to store in the array :");
   scanf("%d",&n);

   printf(" Input %d number of elements in the array :\n",n);
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
      printf(" element - %d : ",i);
      scanf("%d",arr1);
      }
   printf(" The elements you entered are : \n");
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
      {
      printf(" element - %d : %d \n", i, arr1[i]);

      }
       return 0;
}
```

The code is printing random numbers instead of the values inside the array, why is that?

I've just started learning so I'm trying to understand what is going wrong in this situation.

I had other exercises where I could print values from an array just fine using the same method:

Comment: `scanf("%d",arr1);` -> `scanf("%d",&arr1[i]);`

Comment: Also, indices in C start from 0. So `for(i=1;i<=n;i++)` should be `for(i=0;i<n;i++)`

Comment: Another thing: The array only holds `25` elements. So code should check whether `n` is greater than that or allocate array big enough for `n`. Otherwise will result in buffer overflows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you are a beginner, so I will try to not talk too much about pointers or anything. Basically, c arrays are pointers, and scanf expects pointers as well. To get the result you want, the following code will work. I will try to include useful comments.

EDIT: To clarify, the reason you are printing random numbers when you did it is because C will not inialize array values to anything, so it will be random junk. The scanf you are using always puts values at the beginning of the array:       scanf("%d",arr1); So, therefore, the rest of the array will just remain random junk. Posted below is a full solution, however.

EDIT 2: I forgot to change your second for loop to be <, not <=. Just an fyi, generally for loops go i = 0 to i < n, not i = 1 to i <= n. In addition, stdlib.h must be included. free() is used to prevent memory leaks here, although not really needed since program ends, but I assume this code would probably want to be used in multiple places.

```
int  main(void)
{
   int *arr1;
   int i,n;
   printf("Input the number of elements to store in the array : ");
   scanf("%d",&n); /*We have now scanned in how long we want the array to be */
   arr1 = malloc(sizeof(int) * n); /* Dynamically allocate memory for our array */

   printf("Input %d number of elements in the array :\n",n);
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
      printf("element - %d : ",i);
      scanf("%d", arr1 + i); /*We will store the int at the array with an offset of i
The reason we do this is because we want to store it at the correct index
and arr1 is a pointer */
      }
   printf(" The elements you entered are : \n");
   for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
      {
      printf(" element - %d : %d \n", i, arr1[i]); /*We can still 
dereference arr1 with [] */

      }
    free(arr1);   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The second `for` loop indices need to be corrected.  And for completeness would suggest checking the `scanf` return value and showing that `free` should be called.